# Is there a way to code-split poyfills with useBuiltIns: usage?

Tags: webpack, babeljs, core-js

On webpack v4 and babel v7 I want to use the `useBuiltIns: "usage"` option of `@babel\preset-env` to get specific imports for needed polyfills, but I'd like to separate the imported polyfills from my main bundle, and put them into another file, say `polyfills.js` or something.

In the webpack docs on shimming there's an example of [bundling the polyfills into a separate file](https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/#loading-polyfills), but it requires a separate entry file with declared imports. The problem is that with `useBuiltIns: "usage"` you shouldn't declare any import ([see the docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#usebuiltins-usage)), because Babel will take care of it, so sadly this won't work.

So the question is how can I bundle my polyfills together into a separate file while using `useBuiltIns: "usage"`?

Answer (score 0):

```js
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        polyfills: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](@babel|core-js|regenerator-runtime)[\\/]/,
          name: 'polyfills',
          chunks: 'initial',
          priority: 60,
          enforce: true,
          reuseExistingChunk: true
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. Consider updating your answer to explain what this does and how it addresses the problem - this will help not just the OP but others with similar issues. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)